# Unambiguous DateTime representation with NodaTime -- can this be done with less ceremony?

Tags: c#, datetime, nodatime

I have a fairly straightforward notion that I want to represent using Noda Time:

`04/24/2015 4:00pm America/New_York`

To create an unambiguous representation, I've done the following:

```
var _americaNewYork = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("M/d/yyyy h:mmtt");
var localTime = pattern.Parse(formattedDatetime).Value;
var zonedDateTime = localTime.InZoneLeniently(_easternTime);
```

Is there a more concise way to do what I did above? I feel like I should be able to do this with one or two lines instead:

```
var unambiguous = new ZonedDateTime(string textToParse, DateTimePattern pattern, string timezone);
```

And maybe a few overloads if I really want to specify gap semantics when changes occur.

Comment: Feedback is welcome, but preferably on the Noda Time discussion forum.  I don't see anything wrong with your code.  That's just about the right amount of ceremony for Noda Time's current design philosophy.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say that what you've got is actually the best approach at the moment - you're parsing to the right type, in that what you've got in your text ("04/24/2015 4:00pm") really is a local time. (If you've actually got the "America/New_York" bit in there, you should definitely just use a `ZonedDateTimePattern`.)

But you can use a `ZonedDateTimePattern` anyway, with an appropriate resolver and template value:

```
var tzdb = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb;
var pattern = ZonedDateTimePattern.Create(
    "M/d/yyyy h:mmtt",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    Resolvers.LenientResolver,
    tzdb,
    NodaConstants.UnixEpoch.InZone(tzdb["America/New_York"]));
string text = "04/24/2015 4:00pm";

var zoned = pattern.Parse(text).Value;
Console.WriteLine(zoned);
```

Obviously that's more code to start with, but you can reuse the pattern multiple times.

As I say, I'd personally stick with what you've got as it says exactly what you're trying to do: parse a `LocalDateTime` and then resolve that into a particular zone.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't seen the ZonedDateTimePattern.